# Non-question: I really like the site's layout

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

I just would like to say: I really really like the site's layout. It's something that *always* supports my senses navigating the site and does not add confusion or any sort of friction. It's a pleasant and "harmonic" experience, especially due to the font choices and then, maybe more importantly, the color palette.

Comment: But some of us dislike the changes caused by the new topbar (introduced in in beginning of last December). See for example [Bug in the logo appearance with the new black top bar](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4007).

Comment: Changes? Seriously, I don't recall any specific changes. But you and others are totally right about the vertical alignment up top, good catch.